# wxPython thread that does not block the GUI?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, wxpython, blocking

I am new to wxPython and threading. I am trying to move some code into a thread so that it no longer blocks my GUI while executing, and I can push another button to kill the thread. Having done this, however, the code still blocks my GUI. How can I write this code so that my thread does not block the GUI?

```
import wx, sys
import threading
import time


class mywxframe(wx.Frame):

    global sizer2, WorkerThread

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pnl.SetSizer(szr)
        szr2 = sizer2(self, pnl)
        szr.Add(szr2, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(300,-1))
        szr.Add(log, 1, wx.ALL, 10)
        btn3 = wx.Button(pnl, -1, "Stop")
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop)

        szr.Add(btn3, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        redir = RedirectText(log)
        sys.stdout=redir

        szr.Fit(self)
        self.Show()


    def sizer2(self, panel):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK",)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, btn2)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        return sizer


    def WorkerThread(self):    
        self.dead = False
        while (not self.dead):
            for i in range(0,10):
                print "printing", i
                time.sleep(3)

    def OnStart(self, event):
         our_thread = threading.Thread(target=WorkerThread(self))
         our_thread.start()

    def OnStop(self, event):
        self.dead = True


class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self, string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)




app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frm = mywxframe()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Please provide a small runnable example. Also, you do **not** want to call any widget's methods from inside a thread. If you need to interact with wx, use a thread-safe method like wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple problems there.

First of all, if you're going to define `sizer2` and `WorkerThread` as methods, you should use them as methods, not globals.

Next, when you were creating the thread you were calling `WorkerThread` and passing its return value (None) to the thread.  This is where you were blocking the GUI.

```
    def OnStart(self, event):
        our_thread = threading.Thread(target=WorkerThread(self))
        our_thread.start()
```

Instead you should be passing a callable object (`WorkerThread` without the `()`) to the thread so it will then be able to call it in the context of the new thread.

Finally, since `self.out.WriteText` manipulates a UI object it must be called in the context of the GUI thread.  Using `wx.CallAfter` is an easy way to do that.

Here is your example updated with these changes:

```
import wx, sys
import threading
import time

print wx.version()

class mywxframe(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pnl.SetSizer(szr)
        szr2 = self.sizer2(pnl)
        szr.Add(szr2, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(300,-1))
        szr.Add(log, 1, wx.ALL, 10)
        btn3 = wx.Button(pnl, -1, "Stop")
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop)

        szr.Add(btn3, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        redir = RedirectText(log)
        sys.stdout=redir

        szr.Fit(self)
        self.Show()


    def sizer2(self, panel):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK",)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, btn2)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        return sizer


    def WorkerThread(self):    
        self.dead = False
        while (not self.dead):
            for i in range(0,10):
                print "printing", i
                if self.dead:
                    break
                time.sleep(3)
        print 'thread exiting'

    def OnStart(self, event):
        our_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.WorkerThread)
        our_thread.start()

    def OnStop(self, event):
        self.dead = True


class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self, string):
        wx.CallAfter(self.out.WriteText, string)


app = wx.App()
frm = mywxframe()
app.MainLoop()
```